# Accessing a button click of User Control in Parent page UWP

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, uwp-xaml

I have a user control created with name as UserControl.

This user control have a label and a button.

I use this user control in one of my page(lets say Page1), but this user control is generated based on the entries in DB. For eg: I have an entry in DB which has a column with name as 'UC1'. So on page(Page1) load, I dynamically add this usercontrol on the page.

Now when the page is loaded, I want the button click to method to be implemented in Page1 code behind. Could anyone let me know how is this possible. I am facing issue as the use control is dynamically generated and since multiple instances of usercontrols can be generated in the page based on the DB entries.

In short I want to call a method in code behind of parent page for the user control that is dynamically generated inside the parent page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed the Button is named ‘btn1’, and the TextBlock named ‘textBlock1’, you can wire up like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    MyUserControl c = new MyUserControl();
    c.btn1.Click += (o, args) =>   
    {
        c.textBlock1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
    };

    //then add the user control to the page
    this.stackPanel1.Children.Add(c);
}
```

And add an x:FieldModifier attribute to the elements so you can access them from outside.

```
<Button x:Name=“btn1” x:FieldModifier=“public” ...
```

Comment: I am able to set the eventhandler as mentioned above after setting it as public. But the even doesnt get triggered once I click on the button. Is anything else need to be done?

Comment: Thank you I am able to access it now. Now having triggered the button click event from parent page, how can I access the other controls defined in the usercontrol. For eg: I need to change the Text of TextBlock in the user control after the specific button was clicked.

Comment: @MadMax see my updated answer, I use an lambada expression to replace the event handler, in the lambda expression, you can access the specific UserControl.